# SMPS Zener diode replacement

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, zener

I have switch mode power supply (SMPS) rated for 32V 50 watt. I plugged it in main AC, checked its output then unplugged it.

Then to put the SMPS back into its casing, to be on safe side I (tried too) shorted 400V filter cap but accidentally shorted it with something else, the SMPS stopped working after that

Upon diagnostics (randomly probing components) I found a Zener diode completely shorted (aka closed) in both directions and behaves the same way out of the circuit board.

Zener have no other markings other than **24** written on it so can I assume its breakdown voltage is 24V? Also, what other components might have gone bad because of it.

My (blind) guess: it is used for some over voltage protection because I didn't find any other bad component on input or output side, the UC3842 also appears to be fine.

The problem is, I cannot find any 24V Zeners on similar electronic circuits like SMPS or UPS kits, what else can I replace it with?

**Update:**
[image: Circuit trace]

Note: The SMD transistor is so tiny that I only managed to guess its marking using optical lens.

The cathode of the Zener is connected to Vcc.

Comment: It could be part of the snubber circuit if it’s a flyback. Can you take a picture of both the diode and the PCB? Can you trace out a sketch a schematic around the failed diode?

Comment: It is so congested that it is almost impossible to trace it @winny

Comment: Please try. It’s impossible to guess otherwise.

Comment: I tried my best and updated question with what i found @winny

Comment: Very good! That’s certainly not a snubber. Of you know the capsule name and you search for that, zener and 24 you may find it. If not, I would look for clues in some 3842 application note.

Comment: If the 1k is OK, then the UC3842 compensation feedback input may be damaged for speed boost on shutoff.

Comment: I tried looking for clues but found different zener configurations and i am not very good with electronics..1k is fine, any way to test uc3842 comp pin? its not shorted btw

Comment: There is only [one](https://imgur.com/a/kAwWRn6) reason a transistor can be there in that place. A shutdown technique with a transistor or thyristor. Both 1F and 1P are NPN transistors. 1k and Zener go to the base of the transistor. So in case of overvoltage, it stops the control. In the event of a shorted Zener, it constantly senses an overvoltage and disables control. The transistor may have remained operational. So you should be able to boot the system by removing Zener. If everything else is good, it should work without Zener. There just won't be surge protection.

Comment: If it works without Zener, you can measure how much voltage is in place of the Zener. You will need a higher voltage Zener there. Unfortunately, it cannot be sensibly replaced.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work after removing the zener so either zener is essential or something else also have gone bad

Comment: Unfortunately, without a circuit diagram, this is just a guess. Replacing Zener can help you decide if your system has stayed working or not.

Answer (score -1):

**It is working as Voltage Regulation for UC3842**

**You should use 24V zener**

So let's understand how it is working When your tapped pin of transformer gets > 24V Zener start conducting and the 1K resistor sees Vtapped-24V on one of its end. The resistor sees 0.7V on its other leg because of its transistor base. The voltage drop on the resistor is (Vtapped-24V - 0.7V). If this voltage is >0v transistor starts conducting and the COMP pin gets 0V which disable the output signal for the Mosfet driver of your SMPS. If the voltage comes below 24 Volts it again starts the signal. This way it regulates the voltage.

Comment: Removing the zener did not help

Comment: who told to remove the Zener? Do you have any Zener diodes with you?

Comment: it was faulty and was possibly shutting down uc3842, I do but non within the voltage range of 24v @Deepak

Comment: Do you have any zener diode with you?

Comment: We can make series connection to make 24 v or around it